# Running Carbon Tracker in google colab - "No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /path/to/usr/lib64-nvidia"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, nvidia, tensorrt

I want to run the library carbontracker in Google Colab with Python 3.
When I try running it like this:

tracker = CarbonTracker(epochs=100)
for i in range(100):
tracker.epoch_start()
(...)

The kernel restarts and the log shows:
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc8s5.png)

I have installed the packages:
carbontracker
Tensorrt
nvidia-pyindex
nvidia-tensorrt
tensorflow

And I have set the os.environ:
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='/path/to/usr/lib64-nvidia'

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check/make sure you have `libnvinfer`(v7) and `libnvinfer_plugin`(v7) installed.

Relevant: [Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60368298/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libnvinfer-so-6)